# Yarn with Express cannot find binaries

Tags: express, yarnpkg, express-generator

Trying out Express.js and yarn (it's all new to me) and I'm running into the most basic of problems. Yarn doesn't seem to be correctly installing executables.

I can see that binaries are there:

```
$ yarn global ls
yarn global v0.18.1
warning No license field
info express-generator@4.14.0 has binaries:
   - express
✨  Done in 0.39s.
```

But when I try to call express:

```
$ express
-bash: express: command not found
```

Is there something obvious missing?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I'm on macOS Sierrra. I had incorrectly added the yarn bin path to my `.bashrc` when really it should have gone in `.profile`

See Path Setup: https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install